# Joblib doesn't work in Jupyter lab

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter, joblib

Firstly I use the joblib.dump command in my neural network training notebook, in order to dump my pipeline that is fitted on my input data:

```
joblib.dump(prepareinput, "prepareinput.save")
```

Then when I try to load the data in a different notebook in Jupyter lab using:

```
prepareinput = joblib.load('prepareinput.save')
```

It will return the following error:

> No such file or directory: 'prepareinput.save'.

Whilst the file is present in the directory. Then when I export the notebook as script, it will run perfectly. I have also tried using the full path "~/..linktofile../prepareinput.save"
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the output of `!pwd` in your notebook ? Try also the absolute path to the file ?

Comment: !pwd showed its working directory was in a brother/sister directory from which I copied the notebook, even though I restarted the kernel in the copied version. After then shutting down my jupyter and starting it up again, everything worked fine!